# How do I call a a Sub from multiple On Click events in Access VBA?

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a List Form in Access with 7 data fields visible on the form. When the user clicks any one of these fields I want it to run the same sub without any differences based on which one they click. I have it currently set up that each one has their own On Click event that goes to the sub, but I was wanting a cleaner way to handle it.

The code they all run opens a form.

```
Sub Gage_Load()
    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
    
    Dim ID As Variant
    
    ' Ensure that the Table_ID field contains a value before proceeding
    If IsNull(Me.Table_ID) Then
        MsgBox "No record selected or Gage ID is Null. This can happen if the data has not been refreshed in awhile. Please refresh and try again.", vbExclamation, "Error"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    ID = Me.Table_ID
    DoCmd.OpenForm "Gage_Modify", , , , , , ID

    Exit Sub

ErrorHandler:
    MsgBox "An error occurred: " & Err.Description, vbCritical, "Error"
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you change your `Gage_Load` procedure from a subroutine to a function, you could then set the *On Click* properties of those data controls to `=Gage_Load()`

That approach is simpler (less overhead) than creating VBA event procedures for each of them.  However, I'm not sure if you will consider it clean enough.

Comment: Thank you! I tried this before but embarrassingly forgot the () part of it.

Answer (score 1):

Use *WithEvents*.

Class module:

```vb
Option Explicit

' Helper class for form Palette for event handling of textboxes.
' 2017-04-19. Gustav Brock, Cactus Data ApS, CPH.
' Version 1.0.0
' License: MIT.

' *

Private Const EventProcedure    As String = "[Event Procedure]"

Private WithEvents ClassTextBox As Access.TextBox


Public Sub Initialize(ByRef TextBox As Access.TextBox)

    Set ClassTextBox = TextBox
   
    ClassTextBox.OnClick = EventProcedure
   
End Sub


Public Sub Terminate()

    Set ClassTextBox = Nothing

End Sub


Private Sub ClassTextBox_Click()

    Dim ID As Variant
    
    ID = Me!Table_ID.Value

    ' Ensure that the Table_ID field contains a value before proceeding
    If IsNull(ID) Then
        MsgBox "No record selected or Gage ID is Null. This can happen if the data has not been refreshed in awhile. Please refresh and try again.", vbExclamation, "Error"
    Else
        DoCmd.OpenForm "Gage_Modify", , , , , , ID
    End If

End Sub
```

And to load  and unload  the class module in the form, this is the code:

```vb
Option Explicit

' Form to display the Windows Phone 7.5/8.0 colour theme.
' Also works as a basic example of implementing WithEvents for a form.
' 2017-04-19. Gustav Brock, Cactus Data ApS, CPH.
' Version 1.0.0
' License: MIT.

' *

Private ControlCollection   As Collection


Private Sub Form_Load()

    ' Load events for all colour value textboxes.
   
    Dim EventProcedure  As ClassTextboxSelect
    Dim Control         As Access.Control
   
    Set ControlCollection = New Collection
   
    For Each Control In Me.Controls
        If Control.ControlType = acTextBox Then
            Set EventProcedure = New ClassTextboxSelect
            EventProcedure.Initialize Control
            ControlCollection.Add EventProcedure, Control.Name
        End If
    Next
   
    Set EventProcedure = Nothing
    Set Control = Nothing
   
End Sub


Private Sub Form_Unload(Cancel As Integer)

    ' Unload events for all colour value textboxes.
   
    Dim EventProcedure  As ClassTextboxSelect
   
    For Each EventProcedure In ControlCollection
        EventProcedure.Terminate
    Next
   
    Set EventProcedure = Nothing
    Set ControlCollection = Nothing

End Sub
```

Full documentation: [Create Windows Phone Colour Palette and Selector using WithEvents](https://www.experts-exchange.com/articles/29554/Create-Windows-Phone-Colour-Palette-and-Selector-using-WithEvents.html?preview=yawJg2wkMzc%3D).

Current code: [VBA.ModernTheme](https://github.com/GustavBrock/VBA.ModernTheme).

Comment: I do wonder: for which use cases is this better than the zero-additional-code method using `=MyFunction()` ?

Comment: Debugging, @Andre, you know that. Using that method should be avoided by all means; it is a left-over from V1.1(!) There may be special cases (delayed execution), but this case is not such one.

Answer (score 0):

If I correctly understand your question, I'm pretty confident that we cannot be cleaner than that:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click()
    Call Gage_Load
End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click()
    Call Gage_Load
End Sub

'...

Private Sub Button7_Click()
    Call Gage_Load
End Sub

Sub Gage_Load()
    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
    
    Dim ID As Variant
    
    ' Ensure that the Table_ID field contains a value before proceeding
    If IsNull(Me.Table_ID) Then
        MsgBox "No record selected or Gage ID is Null. This can happen if the data has not been refreshed in awhile. Please refresh and try again.", vbExclamation, "Error"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    ID = Me.Table_ID
    DoCmd.OpenForm "Gage_Modify", , , , , , ID

    Exit Sub

ErrorHandler:
    MsgBox "An error occurred: " & Err.Description, vbCritical, "Error"
End Sub
```